# ansible parse extra var use default if regex fails

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2

I have the following code which isn't throwing an error but the fact is empty

```
  - shell: echo '{{ p }}'
    register: results

  - debug:
      var: results

  - set_fact:
      myrepo: "{{ results.stdout | regex_search(regexp,'\\1') | default ( {'0':'global'} ) }}"
    vars:
      regexp: '(.*)/(.*)'
```

Here is the output

```
TASK [command] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "results": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "echo 'tim'", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.095831", 
        "end": "2017-09-06 16:37:19.977023", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2017-09-06 16:37:19.881192", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "tim", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "tim"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myrepo": ""
}
```

The command is `ansible-playbook -i hosts -c local file.yml --extra-vars "p=tim"`  I want myrepo to be `global` if the regex results are empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any parameters [default](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#default) filter is triggered only when value is Undefined. But result of unmatched regexp is an empty string, which is *not* Undefined. You may want to set `boolean` flag:

```
  - set_fact:
      myrepo: "{{ results.stdout | regex_search(regexp,'\\1') | default('global', boolean=True) }}"
    vars:
      regexp: '(.*)/(.*)'
```