# Ansible regex_search with capture groups when no matches

Tags: ansible

A common idiom in Ansible search examples goes like this:

```
result.stdout | regex_search('my-regex', '\\1') | first
```

This works fine as long as there is a match. If there is no match then  `regex_search`, if using capture groups, returns `NoneType` (instead of a list) and the expression fails:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable.
```

It fails because `first` operates on a list, and `NoneType` is not a list.

How can this expression be modified to handle a no match scenario? It's fine to return an empty (or hardcoded default) string in this event. Of course, when there is a match then it should return it.

---

(I read other questions and answers, including the suggested question in the comment, but didn't see a solution specific, and widely cited, example that calls for `default` to provide a list. Other examples only show it used with a string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ansible parse extra var use default if regex fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080638/ansible-parse-extra-var-use-default-if-regex-fails)

Comment: Since `first` wants an iterable, give it an iterable: `result.stdout | regex_search('my-regex', '\\1') | default([None], True) | first`

Comment: Or use `regex_findall` that will always return you a list: `result.stdout | regex_findall('my-regex') | first`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes thank you, using the default works. I was looking for that but fell flat trying to find it. If you want to make this an answer, I'll gladly accept it.